# To check status of outlook whether its connected or disconnected without using Outlook UDF

Tags: autoit

I need to automate to check the status(Disconnected/connected/Trying to connect/Need Password) of outlook without using Outlook UDF.

Below is the code i am trying

```
Global $iPID = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\outlook.exe"
Sleep(600)
Run($iPID, "", @SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED)
Sleep(6000)
;check the Status
$status =
```

Could some one please help me out check the status ??

Answer (score 0):

About the ONLY option I can think of is to use hardcoded coordinates to find if the red X in the lower right when offline is true.

You can use the AutoIt Window Info tool to get the coordinates and the color.